# how to set angular textarea to only begin with certain words

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a textarea defined as:

```
<textarea class="lined" rows="30" name="script_text" ng-model="textContent" placeholder="Enter Script Here" style="width:100%"></textarea>
```

Is it possible to have each line in the text area only start with a certain list of words?

For example, the user can only enter:

```
THIS (doesnt matter what comes after)
IS (doesnt matter what comes after)
ALLOWED (doesnt matter what comes after)
```

But if the user types in:

```
This is a sentence 
next line 
and another line
```

That is not allowed. Is this possible?

Comment: sounds like a terrible user experience

Comment: not really, its for a specific use case. What is the purpose of your comment?

Comment: Even for a specific use case, how are you explaining to the user why certain sentences work and other don't?

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Here a pure Javascript solution. In Angular you can write it with $scope.yourmodel.val() etc.

I tested it with this HTML:

```
<textarea id="text" class="lined" rows="30" name="script_text" ng-model="textContent" placeholder="Enter Script Here" style="width:100%"></textarea>
```

I inserted this value:

```
document.getElementById('text').value
```

Result:

"Bla das ist ein Text
Nochmal blaa"

First: I got a regex to get each line. You have to go bottom to top. Zero is the last line and one, in my example, the first line:

```
document.getElementById('text').value.match('(.*)(?=(\n.*){1}$)')
```

The result:

```
["Bla das ist ein Text", "Bla das ist ein Text", "
Nochmal blaa"]
```

Good: Now you can write a  for, foreach, whatever loop you want.
You count up and use the cnt in your regex. If you got a null, you're finished.
I got for:

```
document.getElementById('text').value.match('(.*)(?=(\n.*){2}$)')
```

a null

Second: You split the each line text by words. The first value is your word:

```
document.getElementById('text').value.match('(.*)(?=(\n.*){1}$)')[0].split(' ')[0]
```

Result: "Bla"

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Angular. You could do a great use of the [ng-pattern directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern).

You could try this:

```
<textarea class="lined" rows="30" name="script_text" ng-model="textContent" placeholder="Enter Script Here" style="width:100%"  ng pattern="/^(THIS|IS|ALLOWED) .*/"></textarea >
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ggderas/asvg9yf1/4/)